# Converting C function into Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm

FINAL EDIT: **I'm wrong**. Nothing in the Redis docs suggest that the counter only reaches 255 around 1 million. Just that by the time 1 million hits are reached, the counter is at 255. Case closed. Look no further.

---

I'm trying to port [Redis' LFU algorithm](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) from C to JS. It uses a Morris Counter.

Constants:

`LFU_INIT_VAL = 5`. Seen [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/c1689166b71f298aec40db877e125c76c178b0ba/src/server.h#L1912).

`lfu_log_factor = 10`. Seen [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/search?q=CONFIG_DEFAULT_LFU_LOG_FACTOR&unscoped_q=CONFIG_DEFAULT_LFU_LOG_FACTOR)

The C function, found [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/a2131f907a752e62c78ea6bb719daf9fe2f91402/src/evict.c#L313-L323).

```
/* Logarithmically increment a counter. The greater is the current counter value
 * the less likely is that it gets really implemented. Saturate it at 255. */
uint8_t LFULogIncr(uint8_t counter) {
    if (counter == 255) return 255;
    double r = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    double baseval = counter - LFU_INIT_VAL;
    if (baseval < 0) baseval = 0;
    double p = 1.0/(baseval*server.lfu_log_factor+1);
    if (r < p) counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

My JS port:

```
LFU_INIT_VAL = 5
lfu_log_factor = 10

function LFULogIncr(counter) {
    if (counter == 255) return 255;
    let r = Math.random();
    let baseval = counter - LFU_INIT_VAL;
    if (baseval < 0) baseval = 0;
    let p = 1.0/(baseval*lfu_log_factor+1);
    if (r < p) counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Running the algorithm 1 million times, and recording the iteration index when the counter increments:

```
let hitFreq = 5
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    let newHitFreq = LFULogIncr(hitFreq)
    if (newHitFreq > hitFreq) {
        console.log(`New counter: ${newHitFreq}, i = ${i}`)
    }
    hitFreq = newHitFreq
}
```

Based on this table which can be found in the link...

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| factor | 100 hits   | 1000 hits  | 100K hits  | 1M hits    | 10M hits   |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0      | 104        | 255        | 255        | 255        | 255        |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1      | 18         | 49         | 255        | 255        | 255        |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 10     | 10         | 18         | 142        | 255        | 255        |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 100    | 8          | 11         | 49         | 143        | 255        |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

According to the above table, with an `lfu_log_factor` of 10, when 1 million hits are reached, the counter should be 255. However, when running my JS code, the counter consistently reaches 255 in ~300k hits. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the result of one run of the JS code, comparing the # of actual hits with the expected # of hits with a `factor` of 10:

- `New counter: 10, i = 149` (Expected ~100, over by 49)
- `New counter: 18, i = 652` (Expected ~1000, under by 348)
- `New counter: 142, i = 96383` (Expected ~100k, under by 3617)
- `New counter: 255, i = 275361` (Expected ~1M, under by 724,639 !!!)

**EDIT:** Hmmm... I'm getting the same results in C as I am in JS. A counter of 255 ends up with ~300k hits.

https://onlinegdb.com/Sy8Y8-SJN

Either the table is wrong/outdated, or I'm conducting the test wrong, or the code is correct and I'm misinterpreting the results.

Comment: It should, based on my googling. In this link: http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf, it says "A random number R between 0 and 1 is extracted.". It goes into more detail if you want to read it.

Comment: Random observation: In the C code `r` is in [0,1] whereas in JS `r` is in [0,1).

Comment: Are you sure that `LFU_INIT_VAL` is the same for both?

Comment: Yes, it should be 5. https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/c1689166b71f298aec40db877e125c76c178b0ba/src/server.h#L1912